Probability of two geometric conditions happening together
I have a problem combining geometry with probability, and I feel like I do not understand the basics to approach this problem.
Let there be two points $\mathbf{p}_1$ and $\mathbf{p}_2$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
If the position of $\mathbf{p}_2$ is given, the probability of $\mathbf{p}_1$ being inside an unit radius distance from $\mathbf{G}_1 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is $\mathrm{P}(E_{\mathbf{p}_1 }) = f(\mathbf{p}_2)$. Similarly, if the position of $\mathbf{p}_1$ is given, the probability of $\mathbf{p}_2$ being inside an unit radius distance from $\mathbf{G}_2 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is $\mathrm{P}(E_{\mathbf{p}_2 }) = f(\mathbf{p}_1)$. There exists another known function $g(\cdot)$ such that $\mathbf{G}_1 = g(\mathbf{p}_2)$ and $\mathbf{G}_2 = g(\mathbf{p}_1)$, when $\mathbf{p}_1$ or $\mathbf{p}_2$ is known.
What is the probability of both $\mathbf{p}_1$ and $\mathbf{p}_2$ being inside an unit radius of $\mathbf{G}_1$ and $\mathbf{G}_2$ respectively.
Apologies if this sounds too basic, but any help would be hugely appreciated.
